# Why cast address to address?

Tags: solidity, addresses, defi

In [defi contracts](https://github.com/iearn-finance/yearn-protocol/blob/develop/contracts/strategies/StrategyDAICurve.sol#L27), I see codes like this

```
address public constant dai = address(0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F);
```

What's the point of casting an address to address? Or is this just messy code? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of value `0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F` is actually *address literal* (https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.7.0/types.html#address-literals) which is not exactly the same as an *address* - although it is easy to convert between these two.

Doing just `address public constant dai = 0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F;` works as well but under the hood Solidity is casting it into an address as it recognizes that it looks like an address (and because you are setting it to an address type).

So you can basically choose. Doing an explicit cast makes the intention clearer - it's often good to be as clear as possible when writing Solidity code.

Comment: Opening statement is wrong. The value of `0x6B1...d0F ` is... well, `0x6B1...d0F`. Its **type** (which is probably what you meant to say) is not `string` but `uint` (or integer in general).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I couldn't find a source which claims that addresses are stored as uints - I changed my answer to talk about *type* of *address literal*.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `0x...` is regarded as an integer in every strongly-typed language (such as Solidity). In fact, even in JS, which is not a strongly-typed language AFAIK, it will be regarded as `Number` rather than `String` (causing a lot of headache to web3.js developers who are not aware of this, as address values typically exceed `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`).

Comment: Could very well be true. However since even Solidity documentation fails to mention this I don't want to mention it - I don't see any reason to confuse things more. The eventual underlying type is not relevant here in my opinion.

Comment: You can try something as simple as `uint256 x = 0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F;`, and see that it compiles well. Replace `uint256` with `string`, and compilation will fail.

Comment: While we're at it, would you mind having a look at [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/90256/16043)? It's an interesting question, but my answer implies that the difference between calling an internal function and an external function can reach up to some 17K gas, which makes no sense to me. AFAIK, an external function call by itself (excluding everything that the function actually does) should be around 1500 gas or so. I've dwelled on it for a while, but I couldn't find anything wrong with how I have conducted the test showing that conclusion. Thanks.